# Tomcat 404 error not serving Java webapp when running eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I've been struggling for 1 month and multiple employees at my company have come across the same issue. Whenever I run my java project on eclipse using Apache Tomcat and open it in my chrome browser, it shows a 404 error. After multiple reinstalls, when I open localhost, tomcat doesn't even work, now I only receive the Chrome default error message: "The site can't be reached".

**Below is a snippet of the logs I receive when I startup my tomcat 7.0 server -->**

```html
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Jun 08, 2021 3:24:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_291/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_291/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_291/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.8.10-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-14.0.2.12-hotspot\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\akpme\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.3\bin;C:\ProgramData\akpme\atom\bin;C:\Users\akpme\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\akpme\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\akpme\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\cmake\cmake-3.19.2-win64-x64\bin;C:\Users\akpme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37;C:\Users\akpme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe;C:\Users\akpme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python3.7.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Users\akpme\.windows-build-tools\python27\;C:\Users\akpme\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.3\bin;C:\ProgramData\akpme\atom\bin;C:\Users\akpme\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\akpme\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\akpme\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Users\akpme\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Programming\SaveAway\eclipse;;.]
Jun 08, 2021 3:24:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
Jun 08, 2021 3:24:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1785 ms
Jun 08, 2021 3:24:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Jun 08, 2021 3:24:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.107
Jun 08, 2021 3:24:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\akpme\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\InSpirAVE\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jun 08, 2021 3:24:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 08, 2021 3:24:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/akpme/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/InSpirAVE/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/akpme/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/InSpirAVE/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
Jun 08, 2021 3:25:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jun 08, 2021 3:25:06 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [409] milliseconds.
Jun 08, 2021 3:25:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
Jun 08, 2021 3:25:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
Jun 08, 2021 3:25:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 22419 ms
```

===========================================================================

[Chrome Browser Screen:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsXbC.png)

==========================================================================

If you need anything else please email me at mahit.py@gmail.com.

Comment: You'll be notified of comments and answers if you check back here, you don't need to put your email address out in public. `Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]` would seem to indicate you're on port 8090, not 8080.

Comment: I changed it to port 8090, but still no luck. The same error screen appears. The chrome browser says, "No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8090/"

Comment: That's not the same error as before. That one's indicative of you not using a correct URI.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know where to go from there. How do I figure out the right link?